# GridView Not showing when i delete the all rows from database table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

i am facing a problem do not know how to set this problem the problem is that my project working fine but when i delete all the rows from sql databse its not show grid kindly help
your response will be highly appreciated

Here is my Code Behind

```
public partial class Web_grid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            BindData();


        }
    }

protected void BindData()
        {
            SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.6;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=malick");

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            conne.Open();

            string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM OPR1 ";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conne);

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adp.Fill(ds);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conne.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
         //   GridView1.DataSource =null;

           // GridView1.DataSource = ds;
          //  GridView1.DataBind();
            //ds = null;
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.6;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=malick");

            conne.Open();

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
            {

                Calendar txtOpenDate = (Calendar)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOpenDate");

                TextBox txtCloseDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCloseDate");

                DropDownList DropDownListoppr = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownListoppr");

                DropDownList DropDownListStages = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownListStages");

                TextBox txtAddLine = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddLine");

                TextBox txtStages = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStages");

                TextBox txtAddOppId = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddOppId");




                string cmdstr = "insert into OPR1(OpenDate,CloseDate,SlpCode,Step_Id,Line,OpprId) values(@txtOpenDate,@txtCloseDate,@SlpCode,@Step_Id,@txtAddLine,@txtAddOppId)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conne);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtOpenDate", txtOpenDate.TodaysDate);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCloseDate", txtCloseDate.Text);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Step_Id", DropDownListStages.SelectedValue.ToString()); // SelectedItem.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlpCode", DropDownListoppr.SelectedValue.ToString()); // SelectedItem.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtStages", txtStages.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAddLine", txtAddLine.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAddOppId", txtAddOppId.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             //   this.TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
           //     this.TextBox3.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();


                BindData();
                conne.Close();
            }

        }
        protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                DropDownList DropDownListoppr = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListoppr");
                DropDownList DropDownListStages = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListStages");

                DataTable CardCode = new DataTable();
                DataTable CardCode1 = new DataTable();

                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.6;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=malick");
                using (connection)
                {



                    SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("select SlpCode,SlpName from OSLP ", connection);
                    SqlCommand theCommand1 = new SqlCommand("select Distinct StepId, Descript from OOST ", connection);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(theCommand);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(theCommand1);

                    adapter.Fill(CardCode);
                    adapter1.Fill(CardCode1);
                    //DropDownList7.DataSource = CardCode;
                    //DropDownList7.DataTextField = "SlpName";
                    //DropDownList7.DataValueField = "SlpCode";
                    //DropDownList7.DataBind();

                    if (CardCode.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < CardCode.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string name3 = CardCode.Rows[i]["SlpName"].ToString();
                            string slpCode = CardCode.Rows[i]["SlpCode"].ToString();
                            DropDownListoppr.Items.Add(new ListItem(name3, slpCode));



                        }
                    }

                    if (CardCode1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < CardCode1.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            string name4 = CardCode1.Rows[j]["Descript"].ToString();
                            string stageCode = CardCode1.Rows[j]["StepId"].ToString();
                            DropDownListStages.Items.Add(new ListItem(name4, stageCode));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't this normal if you _delete_ them in your database? And I don't see _any_ delete command in your code.

Comment: Why it will show the gridview if you have deleted all the records? If you are trying to set any default text when there are no rows then you can use [EmptyDataText property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(v=vs.110).aspx) or [EmptyDataTemplate Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RahulSingh for insertion in grid view i am using grid

Comment: Can you show what code you are using on the HTML side of the page?

Answer (score 0):

No need of  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in BindData Method, As you are not performing any insert,delete or update operation.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this property to your aspx gridview

EmptyDataText="someText"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(v=vs.110).aspx

or you can use  EmptyDataTemplate - just like TemplateField

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is what you'll want to do.